# jQuery: Inserting HTML into a draggable div with .prepend() - how to use the click event on this HTML element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-click-event, jquery-draggable

Following issue: I have a hidden div container called "#window-hidden". When a user clicks on a link the HTML of the linked document should be inserted into this div container by AJAX (working so far". This container should be draggable as well (working so far). But additionally I need a close-button to hide this div container again - and here appears the trouble.

My code:

```
$('.top_navigation .address a').click(function() {
  var myUrl = SOME CODE TO GET THE URL - WORKING;
  $('#window-hidden').load(myUrl, function() {
    var closer = '<div id="closer"><a href="#">X</a></div>';
    $(this).prepend(closer);
    $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  return false;
});

$('#window-hidden').draggable();

$('#closer a').on('click', function() {
  $('#window-hidden').fadeOut();

});
```

The first block of the code loads the HTML into the div container as well as it adds the "closer" element into the container. Everything is fine so far. The second block makes the container draggable. And with the last block of code I wanted to close the window again but it does not work. Maybe it is because the parent container (#window-hidden) is draggable? Or maybe it is because the element #closer is inserted after the DOM was built??

Best,
Tobias

Answer (score 2):

`click` events **only work on elements that exist in the DOM on document ready**. You need to use either [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (if you're using jQuery 1.7+) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (for earlier jQuery versions) to achieve what you need. Try either of these depending on your version:

`on`:

```
$("#window-hidden").on("click", "#closer a", function () {
    $('#window-hidden').fadeOut();
});
```

`delegate`:

```
$("#window-hidden").delegate("#closer a", "click", function () {
    $('#window-hidden').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried it several times in different ways with .on() but did not get the right syntax. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TobiasKirsch No problems glad I could help! :). If this was the answer to your problem, please click the tick next to it and mark it as correct :).

Answer (score 0):

To listen for events on dom elements inserted after page load, you need to use the on method.  In this case it would be something like:

```
$('#window-hidden').on('click', '#closer a', function() {
    $('#window-hidden').fadeOut();
});
```

For more info, see: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that this code here

```
$('#closer a').on('click', function() {
  $('#window-hidden').fadeOut();

});
```

is executed when the page loads, but the 'closer' div is inserted into the DOM when the link is clicked. So at that point in time when you are trying to attach the click handler to the 'closer' div, it does not exist yet.
Can you try putting the event handler attaching into the click handler? Just copying stuff around, it would look like this:

```
$('.top_navigation .address a').click(function() {
  var myUrl = SOME CODE TO GET THE URL - WORKING;
  $('#window-hidden').load(myUrl, function() {
    var closer = '<div id="closer"><a href="#">X</a></div>';
    $(this).prepend(closer);

    $('#closer a').on('click', function() {
        $('#window-hidden').fadeOut();
    });

    $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  return false;
});

$('#window-hidden').draggable();
```

Cheers, Alex